# Line break in Facebook status update via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a simple Facebook *status update* web app that uses Graph API. It works well except for when I'd like to include a line break in the status message.  I've tried adding a simple HTML 
 tag, but this is just rendered as text.

Anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It sounds silly, but this works:
Insert `<center></center>` where you would normally put `<br>`.

Comment: Put <center>&nbsp;</center> for you need than one <br />

Comment: Both <center></center> and <center>&nbsp;</center>works for me.

Comment: In iOS, this does NOT work for preview of text (shows <center></center> which looks ugly), but DOES work once posted to wall!

Comment: Update: Preview shows the <center></center> text in the Description part of a post. But preview looks fine if use the Caption part of the post instead!

Comment: Both <center></center> and <center>&nbsp;</center> worked for me too

Comment: This isn't working for me from the javascript API. Any new solutions?

Comment: For anyone who may be interested, \n is now working for me, from the javascript API.

Comment: <center></center> and \n does not work for me in description field of link

Comment: I've tried <center></center>, \n, \r\n from php sdk, Nothing works for me, at the moment. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Answer of Roger Gajraj is working as of Mar 19, 2014.

Answer (score 12):

\r\n seems to work just fine to get line breaks in facebook

Comment: Don't forget to use double quotes in Php for this to work.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using PHP or any language just add `chr(10)` and this will add a break :) 
ASCII Solution :P

Comment: the only one that wroks from me! Code for sample: 'message' => 'Line 1 '.chr(10).' Line 2',

Comment: This is the correct answer. Others solutions doesn't work now

Answer (score 8):

Please observe the new line that is used in the below code (an enter is hit inside the editor), that serves the purpose of adding new line to a post at a specific location:

```
    $fb_status_with_new_line = "Text before new line" . "
    " . "Text after new line";
```

Answer (score 7):

If you replace return characters (`\r`) with new line characters (`\n`) you can achieve the desired result.

Enjoy...

Comment: Don't forget to use double quotes in Php for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

%0A might work, i think i used that on one of my apps before.

```
HTML Decimal: &#10;
HTML Hexadecimal: &#x0A;
Java Hexadecimal: \u000A (Common To Javascript)
URL Hexadecimal: %0A
Escape Sequence: \n

HTML tag : <br>
```

Hope these come in handy :)

Answer (score 4):

As of Dec 2013, this works (break lines in code):

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> 'Line 1
                                             Line 2
                                             Line 3
                                             Line 4',
                                             'cb' => ''));
```

Answer (score 4):

I've tried `<center></center>` it didn't work. 
I've tried `<br>` it didn't work. 
I've tried with invisible html characters, it didn't work. 
I've tried with `'\n'` it didn't work.

However when I used `"\n"` instead of `'\n'` it worked. But this was recognized directly by the php before it was uploaded to facebook. So my suggestion is using double quotes with string messages in facebook posts.

Comment: Oddly enough, this is the only answer that worked for me as of June 2015

Comment: I use the messenger API, and this is the reverse : the only thing that works is putting the 2-char string '\n', and not the newline char "\n".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP, you can do like this:

```
$message = str_replace('\r\n', "\n", $message); // input is from textarea
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                             'source' => '@' . $photo['file_source'],
                                             'message' => $message)
                                            );
```

Please use double quote `"\n"` instead `'\n'`

Answer (score 1):

\n Worked Its smallest an easiest way to add line breaks

Comment: No <center>, no <br> just "\n" simple and easy!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add carriage return i.e \n\r because facebook accept only enter for new line.

Answer (score 1):

\n works. You just need to add it to the message param

Answer (score 1):

\n working I checked now on twitter. 
 $post = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "first line \n second line"));
Just do it like so, It will work for other social media also

Answer (score 1):

I use the messenger API with PHP.
For me, the string '\n' is working.
Beware that this is not the newline character (aka "\n").
No, it's '\' followed by 'n', aka "plain antislash-N".

Answer (score 0):

if You are using iOS mobile platform the **\n** will supports fine..                            **message = encodeURIComponent(message)** .. bur for android nothing is working for me searching for me..

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions offered worked for me when trying to post a comment on Facebook using Chrome.  The only solution I have found is to highlight text that has a linefeed, then paste in that text, then erase all of the paste except the linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (in bash) newline works only with newline character `$'\n'`, e.g.

```sh
echo "Message text"$'\n'"#kw"
```