# Is there really any clear way of adding line breaks or formatting post while we post to FB wall using PHP or JS SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Feed Dialog for asking my user to post on their or their friend's wall..

I want to format the contents of the post with break lines (the value of 'description' field in feed dialog)..

I tried in facebook forum itself but couldn't find any decisive answers there..

Have any you of tried with any clear way of adding break lines/ formatting texts while we user feed dialog?

I saw in some of the forums stating to add `'<center></center>'` wherever we need a line break.. But i dont think this is proper solution and as FB changes their functionality day/night, i dont want to give a different experience to my users..

I'm in search of a complete solution..!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583507/line-break-in-facebook-status-update-via-graph-api

Comment: @Salt See the comment posted below the answer in the link you provided..  Its status its no longer working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show me an example of a current feed/stream item that has line breaks?  I really don't think Facebook intends that the stream/feed has any "formatting" beyond what they apply to them.  The center tag was a "loophole" which was filled by Facebook, hence why it no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me and one more user but when posted from inside the application, not sure if you get to alter the text from feed dialog.

direct link to the working solution:
[Line break in Facebook status update via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583507/line-break-in-facebook-status-update-via-graph-api/10960799#10960799)