# How to use Linebreak/Newline while posting from Facebook's Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Line break in facebook status update via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583507/line-break-in-facebook-status-update-via-graph-api)

I tried with \n, \r, \r\n, \n\r  but still I'm unable to implement line-break

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of "hacks" reported for doing this, see [Line break in Facebook status update via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583507/line-break-in-facebook-status-update-via-graph-api) but no official update from Facebook

Also "for instance, at one point posting certain strings (like  or %0D%0A) would add a line break to a wall post."