# Facebook post to feed looks bad on mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I post to feed like this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Some text',
    link: 'http://www.google.se/',
    picture: 'http://www.google.se/img/mdh_90x90.png',
    caption: 'Some text is just textbut som is <b>bold</b>',
    description: '1. number one<center></center>2. number two<center></center>3. number three'
});
```

The center tag is for line break. This works perfect in all browsers i've tested except mobile safari in ios 4. In mobile safari i can see the center tags and bold tags. But when posted to facebook it looks good again.

Is there a way solve this?

Edit:
Not really relevant for the question but, i found the center-hack here [Line break in Facebook status update via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583507/line-break-in-facebook-status-update-via-graph-api/5679341)

Edit 2:
[image: Facebook bug]
This is what it looks like. Desktop to the left and mobile to the right. Both looks good when posted to Facebook. Should i report this as a facebook bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen an **official** way to have line breaks (or any formatting actually) in your feeds. Maybe Facebook is disabling them for security reasons or maybe to prevent abusing them.

If Facebook has no plans to support line breaks, you **shouldn't** be using hacks in your code because this may stop working at any minute!

---

I would really like to see an official answer from a Facebook employee about this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- One linebreak:
- Two linebreaks

Answer (score -3):

why don't you use <br /> tags for  linebreak ?
It should work in all browser

Comment: Facebook doesn't understand the meaning of the words "should work" unfortunately. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583507/line-break-in-facebook-status-update-via-graph-api/5679341