# Can't do a line break when my App post

Tags: facebook, post, line, break

I cant find a way to make a line break when my app post on user's facebook. I tried using all of this founded here: [Line break in Facebook status update via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583507/line-break-in-facebook-status-update-via-graph-api)

```
\n 
\r
<center></center>
&#10
&#x0A
\u000A
%0A
```

But nothing works.

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Comment: I mean, are you using the JavaScript, PHP, iOS or Android SDK?

Comment: Try:
`$fb_status_with_new_line = "Text before new line" . "`
`" . "Text after new line"; `, as suggested in the post you supplied.

Comment: I tried it but only works in post message. I need a line break in post description

Comment: Ah. It seems that this is not supported, sorry.