# Post status on Facebook containing HTML tags using javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook

I already tried all the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583507/line-break-in-facebook-status-update-via-graph-api).

I'm trying to post status on Facebook page using JavaScript SDK and it's working fine for me. But I'm facing some strange problem which is whenever I tried to insert a new line or tried to underline a text then on Facebook it's displaying html tag there.

e.g:

I've tried `<center></center>` it didn't work. I've tried `<br>` it didn't work. I've tried with invisible html characters, it didn't work. I've tried with `'\n'`it didn't work. I even used "\n".

The Angular bracket `(<)` is replace by `&lt;`

**Update**

On Facebook side the status looks like this.

`<p>I've tried &lt;center&gt;&lt;/center&gt; it didn't work. I've tried &lt;br&gt; it didn't work. I've tried with invisible html characters, it didn't work. I've tried with '\n' it didn't work.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;However when I used "\n" instead of '\n' it still not worked for me.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Put &lt;center&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/center&gt; for you need than one &lt;br /&gt; sadasdasd asd asd asdasd</p>`

Inside the `<p>` tag all the brackets has been changed.

e.g: this `(<)` will be changed to `&lt;` and this `(>)` will be changed to `&gt;`

**Question**

Is there any way we can use html tags inside Facebook post or is there any way in which enter new line in Facebook post updated using JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line break in Facebook status update via Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583507/line-break-in-facebook-status-update-via-graph-api)

Comment: @RayonDabre I already go through all the answers showed in the link but unable to figure out the way that's why I posted it as a question

Comment: Show us your efforts so that one could debug that code!

Comment: @RayonDabre I Updated the question again. Please check what I did earlier. No links were posted and no new line is posted to Facebook using JavaScript SDK

Comment: `However when I used "\n" instead of '\n' it worked.` – if it works, then what exactly is the problem? // I have always used `\n` for line breaks in FB status messages, and that has always worked fine.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I just updated my question again it was dummy text. It's not working out for me. I tried different things so that I can enter a new line from JavaScript SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, Facebook posts can't contain any HTML.