# Facebook Messenger API:how to break line in a message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

In Facebook Messenger chat,we can break a line by press "SHIFT+ENTER".
So how to break line by Facebook Graph API(Messenger API).
I've seen in a few answers that the Graph API accepts `<center></center>` instead of `<br>` and some other parts of their API seem to accept `\r\n`.

Is there currently any way of sending a line break and if there is where it it documented?

Comment: Since the `text` property has a 320 character limit anyway, I would not be surprised if they did not enable posting text with line breaks. Maybe rather split the text at line breaks on your end, and then send them as individual messages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using php, You should be use `chr(10)` . Its working as like `'\n'` or `'<br>'`.  Also you can use `<center></center>` . Its working for me.

Comment: @FMan .. k dear.. But its working fine for me.. If your answer working good for you.. then enjoy the code.. if You want any more help from me.. please provide me your code .

Comment: Ideally he should use PHP_EOL for this

Answer (score 16):

Turns out [Line break in Facebook status update via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583507/line-break-in-facebook-status-update-via-graph-api) might give you what you are looking for:

Use \u000A

For me it solved my similar issue I had with Facebook SendApi for a Facebook Messenger Bot.

Answer (score 6):

I had to use \n\n for the line break to work.

e.g.

```
"Sorry, We don't have any information ragarding this.\n\nSay 'Hi' to startover"
```

shows following in facebook messenger

```
Sorry, We don't have any information ragarding this.
Say 'Hi' to startover
```

Comment: Hi there. Can you please add some example for more clear answer. tnx

Comment: I used "\n\n" as a new line break inside my string which I sent to the chatbot. It worked for PHP. Example "This is some text I am sending to my chatbot. \n\n This is a new line".

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to get a line break in the welcome text that shows up before users touch Get Started in my Messenger bot. I found that "\n" worked but ONLY in the mobile version of Messenger. It doesn't work on the web at the moment. Assuming that will get fixed at some point because Facebook shows line breaks in their blog post this week (9/12/2016) https://messengerblog.com/bots/messenger-platform-1-2-link-ads-to-messenger-enhanced-mobile-websites-payments-and-more

Answer (score 2):

Though it is not documented, but I suppose "\r\n" would work.
Graph api returns the json response as "\r\n" for messages or posts having a line break.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what language you're using to build your bot, but if you're using PHP then \n needs to be wrapped in double quote strings e.g

```
  $message = "Message \n with a line break";
```

using single quotes (') won't work.

Though a better solution if using PHP would be to use the PHP_EOL constant

Whatever language you're using to build your bot may have similar quirks

Answer (score 2):

Use language specific line separators.

```
Java System.lineseprator 

php PHP_EOL 

Python os.linesep 

Nodejs os.EOL
```

When we use special character in string then JSON conversion understand it as part of string.

Answer (score 1):

In Python `\\n` breaks the line as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Convert "\n" in your text to "\n" => it working...
With Php this is my code: (tested)

```
$_text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "\\n", $_text);
```