# Facebook Messenger bot text formatting

Tags: php, json, facebook, bots, messenger

I have the following message that my fb messenger bot replies to the users:

```
$message_to_reply = "To get travel info, reply in the format\nOrigin*Destination*TraveDate\nExample: City 1*City 2*$selected_date";
```

I am trying to add line breaks using `\n` but looks like its not working. I have also tried `chr(10)`, `'\n'`, `'<br>'`and `<center></center>` and none of them is working for me. anyone faced the same issue and any work around?

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100495/facebook-messenger-apihow-to-break-line-in-a-message