# Can't add line break when sending messages on Facebook Channel

Tags: node.js, markdown, botframework

Referencing this closed issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/920

I have the same problem as the author, on Facebook channel: I'd like to add line breaks but I can't. I tried things I saw on other threads like `<br>`, `<br />`, `&nbsp;` , \n \n, \r\n, \r \n... Nothing works.

In my below examples, `ServicesToDisplay` is just an array of strings joined by '  \n' (space space \n, because bot framework strings are as I saw, in `Markdown`).
Only one thing works, adding a random string:

```
session.send(`Interventions le ${results.response.entity}:

qwe


${servicesToDisplay}`);
```

Leads to well interpreted line breaks:

[image: https://puu.sh/wrdV5/3719ccf115.png]

And without the string:

```
session.send(`Interventions le ${results.response.entity}:



${servicesToDisplay}`);
```

It leads to no line break:

[image: https://puu.sh/wrdYs/42d23f7c36.png]

Do you have any idea on how to perform the same behaviour without the string between ?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100495/facebook-messenger-apihow-to-break-line-in-a-message to see if there is anything useful

Comment: Thanks for your link. However, I tried all solutions on your thread and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @PierreHofman are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: @JasonSowers Yes I do, I gave up for now after a lot of tries

Comment: Sorry I had no luck.

Comment: Still If you have a solution about this @JasonSowers, do not hesitate ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I know its so late, but I made it work by using the following,

Let your message to send is: "hello \n how are you \n\n :)", 
Then before sending it through the API, format it like ,

`message = message.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');`

Send this message using API, and you will get the line breaks. It worked for me.