# How to create a list in amazon lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I would like to create an ordered list response with Amazon Lex, I tried HTML and Markdown in the "Custom Markup" area but nothing worked.

HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

Markdown:

```
1.  Item
2.  Item
3.  Item
```

Comment: How a response is displayed to the user is completely dependent on the channel (Facebook, SMS, Webchat, etc). Which channel are you trying to make this work for?

Comment: The chatbot is for facebook

Comment: Try one of these solutions, creating a line break after each item instead of a real OL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100495/facebook-messenger-apihow-to-break-line-in-a-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to responses and click 'Add Message' in the lex console then you can format your list like this `Item\n Item\n Item`.
It won't display a formatted list in the lex console but it will work on Facebook Messenger.